# Add Lua to OSX path/env variable

Tags: macos, lua

After building Lua 5.3.4 on OSX Sierra as per the README document instructions, I can only run Lua by going into the src directory and typing ./Lua as you would on an executable.

Should I have built Lua differently?

What do I need to do get it to run by typing Lua in the terminal as I've seen in most of the install HOW-TO documents instead of going to the src directory every time to run the executable? Is this related to having it in my env path?

Comment: Have you tried `make install` as mentioned in the [README](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html)?

Comment: I have followed the exact instructions on the README document.

Comment: Does `lua` appear in `/usr/local/bin`? if so, is  `/usr/local/bin` in your shell `PATH`?

Comment: it does not appear in the/usr/local/bin. it's only in the src folder of the Lua folder where I built it. I just have the normal executable in the folder as if i'd just compiled a "hello world" program in C.

Comment: Then you haven't do `make install` (in `../src`).

Comment: More specifically you'll probably need to `sudo make install`